# C# Authenticate to SharePoint without hard coded password

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I connect to a SharePoint website using SharePointOnlineCredentials. There are many examples using a hard coded password. But how can I connect to the SharePoint Website without a hard coded password?

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://company.sharepoint.com");
SecureString securePassWord = new SecureString();
string pwd = "1234";
pwd.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(s => securePassWord.AppendChar(s));
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("mail@company", securePassWord);
```

Comment: The connection shall be done with the current users login data. How can I get the current user's credentials and insert it as login data?